# How to Open textview url within our application?

Tags: iphone

We have TextView control with some website url, if we click the textview website url, it is automatically open the safari browser, how to open the this webpage within our application?

Answer (score 0):

I subclass a webview and give it a method inside like this:

```
    -(void)loadWebPageFaceBook{
    NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.facebook.com" ];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    tabBar.selectedItem = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    [self loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [url release];
    [urlRequest release];
    }
```

the tabBar part is cos I have a tab controller at bottom with a couple hyperlinks, this is like a small sandboxed browser..

obviously you could be feeding the URL as a NSString (@"www.someWebsite.com") argument into the method call, modifying above to something like..

```
    -(void)loadWebPage:(NSString)urlString{
     NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: urlString ];
     NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
     [self loadRequest:urlRequest]; 
     [url release];
     [urlRequest release];
     }
```

and then call that from your view controller, something in the textfield should return...

```
    if ([myTextFieldObject.text length > 0]){
    NSString *urlEntry = myTextFieldObject.text;
    [myWebViewObject loadWebPage:urlEntry];
```

the webView object will also need a method to deal with errors, when there is no network/internet connection, and when the URL is bad.   hope that helps

Comment: Hi Jef, I have textview with content of url, when i click that url,it is opening the outside app. i need to open it in webview controller.

Comment: yes, thats what i was telling you how to do.   Make a new file, subclass of UIWebview..   put that method inside it..   and call on it with the contents of your text input box.. should work fine for you mate